# Is it possible to call more than one function within a javascript function parameter list

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript callback or higher order functions. Please help me in understanding the mistake in the following functions. I am trying to call more than function as callback functions. Is it not allowed?

My code is:

```
var firstFunction = function(item1){
    console.log("calling firstFunction");
    console.log(item1);
}
var secondFunction = function(item2, f1){
    console.log("calling secondFunction");
    f1(item2);
}
//secondFunction("first", firstFunction);

var thirdFunction = function(item3, f2,f1){
    console.log("calling thirdFunction");
    f2(item3);
}

thirdFunction("second", firstFunction, secondFunction);
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aren't promises just callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539815/arent-promises-just-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

What you did is correct, But you have to pass f1 as a call back in third function

```
var thirdFunction = function(item3, f2,f1){
    console.log("calling thirdFunction");
    f2(item3, f1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay, there are no restrictions as for callback depth, but be awared of [stack overflow errors.](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/19/javascript-stack-overflow-error/)

In your code you are executing firstFunction inside third one, after that script stops. I suppose to think that you wanted to execute secondFunction inside the thirdFunction and then first inside the second:

```
function firstFunction (item){
    console.log("calling firstFunction");
    console.log(item);
}

function secondFunction (item, f1){
    console.log("calling secondFunction");
    f1(item);
}

function thirdFunction (item, f1,f2){
    console.log("calling thirdFunction");
    f2(item,f1);
}

thirdFunction("second", firstFunction, secondFunction);
```

that code would work in described way.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this script

```js
var firstFunction = function(item1, f2) {
  document.body.innerHTML += item1 + " | This is firstFunction <br/> ";
  //console.log("calling firstFunction");
  f2(item1, secondFunction);
}
var secondFunction = function(item2, f1) {
  document.body.innerHTML += item2 + " | This is  secondFunction <br/> ";


}


var thirdFunction = function(item3, f1, f2) {
  document.body.innerHTML += item3 + " | This is thirdFunction <br/> ";
  f1(item3, f2);

}

thirdFunction("chain started third function", firstFunction, secondFunction);
```

```html
<html>

<body></body>

</html>
```